# How to do php operations in drupal

Tags: mysql, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I am absolute beginner to drupal.

I have added a contact form (using `Webform module`).

Now I want to save the data entered in the form. But I am lost. I have searched over internet, found `db_query()` is used to query database.

But I dont know where to write the php code. Please help me or if you know any link,please give me.

Comment: Webform already saves form submission data to the database, are you trying to save the data again in a separate table?

Comment: No,I just want to know where it saved and how can I process those data for other operations.

Comment: No problem, what version of Drupal (6 or 7) are you using? The syntax varies a fair bit depending on version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables you'll be most interested in are `webform`, `webform_submissions`, `webform_submitted_data` and `webform_component`. Have a look at those tables and it becomes very obvious how they're linked together.

You'll want to look at the [Drupal 7 Database API](http://drupal.org/developing/api/database) to learn how to use the query system but here's an example to get you going:

```
/* Get a list of all submissions from webform for the node with ID (`nid`) of 1 */
$nid = 1;
$submissions = db_select('webform_submissions', 'ws')
  ->fields('ws')
  ->condition('nid', $nid)
  ->execute();

/* If you want to use db_query and a plain old SQL statement instead you'd do it like this: 
$submissions = db_query('SELECT * FROM webform_submissions WHERE nid = :nid', array('nid' => $nid)); */

/* Loop through the submissions and load up the submitted data for each */
$submission_data = array();
foreach ($submissions as $submission) {
  $query = db_select('webform_submitted_data', 'wsa')
    ->fields('wc', array('name'))
    ->fields('wsa', array('data'))
    ->condition('sid', $submission->sid);

  /* Join in the component table to get the element label */
  $query->join('webform_component', 'wc', 'wc.nid = wsa.nid AND wc.sid = wsa.cid');

  $submission_data[] = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();

}
```

At the end of that code you'll have an array (`$submission_data`), which contains a list of arrays of submission data for the provided node. Each of those arrays' items has a key of the component label, and a value of the submitted user value.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks clive ! That helpd me a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that for most normal use cases you'll never need to look at the databases or do any kind of coding. The UI allows you to view submissions of a form (and see what was submitted). You can also configure the Webform to send you a copy of each submission (via email)... There is a lot you can do without "looking under the hood" or messing with the database in any way.

If you are really new to Drupal and Webforms, I just thought I'd point that out. There are a lot of tabs in the UI which might easily be overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Webform has Views support, so you probably don't really need to write database queries to generate the report you want.